# Open html with html viewer app

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open a local html file with html viewer app.
I use below code to do it:

```
MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String mimetype = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension("html");

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(HTML File), mimetype);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

But this will popup chooser contain html edit app.
I only want to display html reader app.
How can I do it?

Comment: Try doing "text/html" in setdataandtype method in the second argument

Comment: The mimetype is same as "text/html".

Comment: Do you have a html viewer app installed ?

Comment: Yes, but this method will list app html viewer and html edit app. I only want to list html viewer app.

Comment: I have posted an answer. please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let try with this code. We will query activities that can open this mime type and find exactly htmlviewer app. Try your self. I don't test so don't sure it working right but it is main idea.

```
MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String mimetype  = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension("html");    

Intent htmlIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
htmlIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(htmlFile), mimetype);

PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> canViewActivity = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(htmlIntent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo resolve : canViewActivity) {
    if ((resolve.activityInfo.name).contains("html_viewer_package")) {
        final ActivityInfo htmlActivity = resolve.activityInfo;
        final ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(htmlActivity.applicationInfo.packageName, htmlActivity.name);
        htmlIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        htmlIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
        htmlIntent.setComponent(componentName);
        startActivity(htmlIntent);
        break;
   }
}
```

Comment: But this method need all htmlviewers' app name and package name's mapping table, and filter by the table?

Comment: Yes. I think there are not too much html viewer app. And default html viewer app will have specific package.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package.name.of.destination.app");
                    startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Form there the control goes to that app, so if you wanna give some effects, you have to do it in the target app